# How to exclude linebreaks from a regex match in python?

Tags: python, regex

How can I make the bellow regex exclude matches that span across lines?

```
import re
reg = re.compile(r'\b(apple)(?:\W+\w+){0,4}?\W+(tree|plant|garden)')
reg.findall('my\napple tree in the garden')
reg.findall('apple\ntree in the garden')
```

The first one should match, the second one should not.
(Now both matches...)

Comment: Replace `\W` with `[^\w\n]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\W` matches newlines. To exclude them replace `\W` with `[^\w\n]`:

```py
import re
reg = re.compile(r'\b(apple)(?:[^\n\w]+\w+){0,4}?[^\n\w]+(tree|plant|garden)')
print(reg.findall('my\napple tree in the garden'))
#  [('apple', 'tree')]
print(reg.findall('apple\ntree in the garden'))
#  []
```